# EOF faults and keep alive

Tags: web-services, soap, network-programming, keep-alive

I have a SOAP server process that fails with "EOF" errors. Does anybody know if EOF faults are related with keep alive timeouts? If yes how? My code is in C/C++

Comment: Can you give us the actual error you're seeing and the code that's reporting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore this topic. It is not generic behavior. This topic is bound to my software.

Comment: If you feel it appropriate, you should be able to delete your own question.